# Pentaho CDE Analyzer Component Date Range Parameter

Tags: mondrian, pentaho-cde

I have created an xanalyzer file with date range parameter "Date". I am using this view in CDE analyzer component with date range parameter. I used date range component to pass start and end date to "Date" parameter in xanalyzer file.

The analyzer component is taking the default dates in analyzer file instead of the start and end dates from the date range parameter.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. Just use Date_START and Date_END in CDE analyzer component and pass the respective start and end date parameter to it.